# Rails Friendly_Id on Heroku, Heroku not updating slugs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, friendly-id

I've set up the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/) gem, following along to the [RailsCasts Screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid) on it. Locally this works brilliantly, I installed it, ran through `User.find_each(&:save)` which successfully updated the slug field on each of the existing users and all was fine.

I have now pushed this to Heroku, and although it works fine for any new members that are added, Heroku isn't updating the user slug for me for already existing Users.

Running `heroku run console` and then `User.find_each(&:save)` just does nothing:

```
irb(main):001:0> User.find_each(&:save)
  User Load (20.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" >= 0) ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
    (23.6ms)  BEGIN
    (2.0ms)  COMMIT
    (13.6ms)  BEGIN
    (21.1ms)  COMMIT
=> nil
```

The relevant code in `models/user.rb` is:

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
  new_record?
end
```

And I've run all DB migrations on Heroku and they went fine. I checked and the `users` table does have a `slug` field, but it's empty and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. If anyone happens to have come across this before, any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

And of course, it's always something silly. I'm really not sure how I missed this:

This piece of code:

```
def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
  new_record?
end
```

Which is there to stop new slugs being made if the name is changed, was also stopping it updating previous posts.

I solved the issue by commenting this out, pushing, running the Heroku console & then `User.find_each(&:save)` worked just fine, I then un-commented the code & pushed to Heroku again, and everything is dandy.

Hopefully this may help someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was history:

```
friendly_id :text, use: [:slugged, :history]
```

Had to be

```
friendly_id :text, use: :slugged
```

To make the heroku save work... I then readded the history part

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by changing my `should_generate_new_friendly_id?` method from

```
  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    title_changed?
  end
```

to

```
  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    slug.nil? || title_changed?
  end
```